# What exactly does "variable initializer is redundant" mean?

Tags: javascript

So I am using Webstorm IDE for some JavaScript and I believe it uses JSLint to inspect the code. I have a bunch of `variable initializer is redundant` warnings. I can't find anything about what it exactly means in terms of what I need to fix.

Example:

```
function calcPayNow(){
    var payNowVal = 0;
    --snip---
    payNowVal = (Math.round(tec * x) - Math.round(allpmts * x)) / x;
   --snip--
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It means that there is no purpose to assigning 0 because it is never used before you assign a different value.

I would change it from:

```
var payNowVal = 0;
--snip---
payNowVal = (Math.round(tec * x) - Math.round(allpmts * x)) / x;
```

to

```
--snip---
var payNowVal = (Math.round(tec * x) - Math.round(allpmts * x)) / x;
```

Comment: In javascript, it is recommended to declare variables at the top of the block and initialize them. What if the first assignment of the variable depends on some values generated after declaration of variable? doesn't the recommendation become contrary in this case?

Comment: @AnkitTanna Who recommends declaring your variables at the top of the block?  Javascript isn't C89.  _I_ recommend declaring variables no earlier than they are needed, and initializing them when declared.  Often times my practice completely avoids the issue at hand here, and allows the variable to be declared as `const` (in ES2015) and helps with writing correct code, verifying the correctness of the code, and comprehending the code when reading it.

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning the value `0`, but that value is never used. It's discarded immediately when you reassign it.

Change to:

```
function calcPayNow(){
    var payNowVal;
    --snip---
    payNowVal = (Math.round(tec * x) - Math.round(allpmts * x)) / x;
   --snip--
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**TypeScript quickfix "Variable initializer is redundant" results in invalid code.**

The code

```
let sss : number = 4;
sss = 5;
```

triggers a "Variable initializer is redundant" inspection on line 1. Applying the quick fix results in:

```
let sss : number: number;
sss = 5;
```

but instead it should be:

```
let sss : number;
sss = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're initializing `payNowVal` here:

```
var payNowVal = 0;
```

And presumably never *using* that value, then later setting it to:

```
payNowVal = (Math.round(tec * x) - Math.round(allpmts * x)) / x;
```

So the initialization does nothing for you. It's redundant.

Leave it off, or better yet, don't declare it until you have a value:

```
function calcPayNow(){
  // --snip---
  var payNowVal = (Math.round(tec * x) - Math.round(allpmts * x)) / x;
  //--snip--
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that you are unnecessarily initialising your variable. Omit that `= 0`, you're never needing (using) it. Or just do

```
var payNowVal = (Math.round(tec * x) - Math.round(allpmts * x)) / x;
```